# "Class not registered" error when working with excel and visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, excel-interop

Hello i'm trying to import data from an excel to visual basic variables, but im getting an strange error. I did add the reference to microsoft excel com library.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    ExtraerCostos()
End Sub

Public Sub ExtraerCostos()

    Dim numero As String
    Dim aux As String
    Dim costos(20) As Double
    Dim cant As Integer  

    Dim excelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim workbook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ' The error points to this line 
    Dim sheet As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = True
    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\workbook.xls")
    sheet = workbook.Worksheets("Factura Detallada")

     'Irrelevant code
    numero = "111111111"
    cant = 12

    While numero.Length = 9
        cant = cant + 1
    End While

    For i = 12 To cant

        numero = sheet.Cells(i, 1).text
        For j = 3 To 22
            aux = sheet.Cells(i, j).text
            If aux = "-" Then
                costos(j - 2) = 0
            Else : costos(j - 2) = Convert.ToDouble(aux)

            End If
            Console.WriteLine(costos(j - 2))
        Next


    Next

End Sub
End Module
```

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't create a workbook or worksheet in this way.
you have to use the Workbooks.Open or Workbooks.Add method (you do that in line 10 of ExtraerCostos)

use

Dim workbook as Excel.Workbook

and already was okay

Answer (score 1):

... You declared it as New workbook, but didn't set it to a value...
Try this:

```
Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
```

Hope this helps